# C# Kinect Drawing Point Over Tracked Hand

Tags: c#, kinect

I have the following code:

```
if (frame != null)
                {
                    canvas.Children.Clear();
                    _bodies = new Body[frame.BodyFrameSource.BodyCount];

                    frame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(_bodies);

                    foreach (var body in _bodies)
                    { 
                        if (body != null)
                        {
                            if (body.IsTracked)
                            {
                                // choose which hand to track
                                string whichHand = "right"; //change to "left" in order to track left hand
                                Joint handRight = body.Joints[JointType.HandRight];


                                if (whichHand.Equals("right"))
                                {

                                    string rightHandState = "-"; //find the right hand state

                                    switch (body.HandRightState)
                                    {
                                        case HandState.Open:
                                            rightHandState = "Open";
                                            break;
                                        case HandState.Closed:
                                            rightHandState = "Closed";
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    canvas.DrawPoint(handRight, _sensor.CoordinateMapper);
                                }
```

Here is my DrawPoint code:

```
public static void DrawPoint(this Canvas canvas, Joint joint, CoordinateMapper mapper)
{
    if (joint.TrackingState == TrackingState.NotTracked) return;

    Point point = joint.Scale(mapper);

    Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse
    {
        Width = 20,
        Height = 20,
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue)
    };

    Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, point.X - ellipse.Width / 2);
    Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, point.Y - ellipse.Height / 2);

    canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
}
```

And Scale:

```
public static Point Scale(this Joint joint, CoordinateMapper mapper)
{
    Point point = new Point();

    ColorSpacePoint colorPoint = mapper.MapCameraPointToColorSpace(joint.Position);
    point.X *= float.IsInfinity(colorPoint.X) ? 0.0 : colorPoint.X;
    point.Y *= float.IsInfinity(colorPoint.Y) ? 0.0 : colorPoint.Y;

    return point;
}
```

The problem that I have is that while the circle does get drawn, it is not drawn over my hand. Instead it stays in the top left corner (0,0), so I'm guessing that it's not getting updated properly. Could anybody tell me what is going on or what the problem is? I would like it to be in the center of my hand (which is being tracked fine because the state of the hand gets updated immediately) and follow my hand as I move it.

The _sensor is my Kinect sensor.

Comment: Do you have add a canvas into your xml file ? because this for me working